# Adjust Width of Button to match another, autosized one

Tags: javascript, asp.net, webforms, updatepanel

I have an ASP.NET page with two buttons `btnConfirm` and `btnAbort`. `btnConfirm`'s width is not set, so it autosizes to fit.
I want to have `btnAbort` to be the same width as `btnConfirm`.

Problem: Both buttons are in an initially invisible `panel`, which is shown by a button click in an update panel. That means, that initially the buttons don't exist on the page.

There are solutions, but they usually apply to always visible controls as far as I see it. Solutions I found/tried are

**Set fixed width to both buttons**
I don't want that, because I can't be sure how large fonts are going to be.

**Set width in Code Behind**
I tried setting the width of `btnAbort` in code-behind. I tried it in `Page_Load` as well as in the `Button_Click` handler, that shows the panel

```
pnlConfirm.Visible = true;
btnAbort.Width = btnConfirm.Width;
```

However, `btnConfirm.Width` is still empty even when it is visible.

**Set the width through JavaScript**
I added a script to the start of the page

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var Abortbtn = document.getElementById("<%= btnAbort.ClientID %>");
    var Confirmbtn = document.getElementById("<%= btnConfirm.ClientID %>");
    Abortbtn.style.width = Confirmbtn.style.width;
</script>
```

However, from debugging in the browser it seems that `Abortbtn` and `Confirmbtn` are always zero (due to being invisible I presume), and the script is not executed again, when the UpdatePanel is updated to show the panel.

**Binding the width property**
I changed the `btnAbort` markup to bind the `Width` property to the other button

```
<asp:Button runat="server" Width="<%# btnConfirm.Width %>" ID="btnAbort" Text="Abort" OnClick="Abort_Clicked" />
```

I called `Page.DataBind()` in `Page_Load`. This didn't seem to change anything (possibly, since the Width property of `btnConfirm` is never set in the first place).

Now I'm out of ideas. Can this be done to keep the dimensions of the controls dynamic, or should I just set them to fixed width and be done with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to run your JavaScript code after the `UpdatePanel` updates. You can use the following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function BeginRequestHandler(sender, args) {
        //code that runs when an UpdatePanel starts refreshing
    }

    function EndRequestHandler(sender, args) {
        //code that runs when an UpdatePanel has finished refreshing.
        var Abortbtn = document.getElementById("<%= btnAbort.ClientID %>");
        var Confirmbtn = document.getElementById("<%= btnConfirm.ClientID %>");

        // If this is true, both buttons exist in DOM
        if(Abortbtn != null && Confirmbtn != null) {
            Abortbtn.style.width = Confirmbtn.offsetWidth+"px";
        }
    }

    var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();

    prm.add_beginRequest(BeginRequestHandler);
    prm.add_endRequest(EndRequestHandler);
</script>
```

With the above code the `BeginRequestHandler` function is called every time when an `UpdatePanel` starts updating and the `EndRequestHandler` function is called every time when an `UpdatePanel` has updated.

Since these handlers will be triggered for any `UpdatePanel` gets updated, you will probably need to have some check to avoid possible errors.

Comment: Great trick. This put me on the right track. However `Confirmbtn.style.width` didn't actually give me the width again, I had to use the line `Abortbtn.style.width = Confirmbtn.offsetWidth+"px";` instead. Would be great if you could change this detail to have a working solution on the site.

Comment: Updated my answer.